# Restrict the "sending data" time for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very small server (less than 1GB of memory) on which I am running MySQL and apache. There exists a php script that runs a MySQl query and shows the data. I modified the query in a way that the results returned would be millions of rows. While the query itself is not super complex, given my server's limited resources, it takes MySQL a long time to deliver the data back to PHP.

Despite setting `max_execution_time` to `30` in php.ini and setting both `wait_timeout` and `interactive_time` to `30` in my.cnf, the server still allows the scrip to be stuck for several minutes. When I run `show full processlist` on MySQL I see that the query is in "Sending data" stage.

My question: how can I restrict the duration of the "Sending data" phase?

Comment: Use pagination instead of requesting all data.

Comment: Fair point. But I'm still curious if there is a config that I could use to just timeout the queries if their data delivery takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with PDO using `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` and `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` for MySQL 5.7+

Working example

```php
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:the_rest_of_dns;', 'usrname', 'passwd', [
    // Set time in miliseconds
    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=200;'
]);

$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM answers");

/* 
 Catch mysql exception
*/
if(($error = $pdo->errorInfo())[0] !== "00000") {

    /*
     Query execution was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded
     exception exception handler
     */
    if($error[1] === 3024) {
        // Die with default error message
        die($error[2]);
    }
}

// If everything working fine, get the result
print_r($result->fetchAll());
```

One important note

> The timeouts only apply to read-only SELECT queries.

If you don't want to set timeout on all queries, you can just type-hint that using:

```sql
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */ status, count(*) FROM articles GROUP BY status ORDER BY status;
```

The second example was taken from [here](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/use-timeouts-to-prevent-long-running-select-queries-from-taking-down-your-mysql).

Comment: I would imagine the query itself has already ‘ended’ while “sending data” (ie. network traffic/throughout?).

Comment: Sending data is not only network traffic, it's also searching the data in the database. So i thougth that restricting execution time would be good soultion. And unfortunately I dont know how to restrict only network traffic

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-thread-states.html you can read here more about states, there is a information that sending data state includes also read disk access (read)